# How to pass variables in php using GET without type?

Tags: php

```
 <form method="get" action=..... >

                      Food <input name="food" type="text"  size="1" />
                  Pizza <input name="pizza" type="text"  size="2" />
                  Drink <input name="drink" type="text" size="2"/>
```

Now I want to pass a third variable which is a concatenation of food+pizza+drink in the URL
I don't want to create a new `<input name="total" type="text" size="2"/>`

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I want to do it before submitting the values.

```
I will have a url like
 http://www.abc.com/&food=tasty&pizza=cheeze&drink=pepsi
I want the url to be
 http://www.abc.com/&food=tasty&pizza=cheeze&drink=pepsi&total=tastypizzacheezepepsi
```

Comment: How would you differentiate between someone ordering 11 food and 2 pizzas and 1 drink v.s. someone ordering 1 food and 1 pizza and 21 drinks? Both would be `1121`.

Comment: @MarcB i assume the OP meant adding, not concatenate

Comment: re: your update: why do you want to add a get variable?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't just do it on the server side?

```
$allTogether = $_GET["food"] . $_GET["pizza"] . $_GET["drink"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Well once it is submitted just concatenate (after validation)

```
$total = $_GET['food'] + $_GET['pizza'] + $_GET['drink'];
         //assuming the _GETs were numbers, otherwise use `.` to concatenate
```

Or if you don't want to do that, you would have to do some JavaScript magic on the client side (but that is not always trustworthy)

Comment: You meant to use `.` instead of `+` to concatenate the string values, perhaps?

Comment: @Phoenix, depends on what the information was. the OP used `+`

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  It did not occur to me that the values of those inputs could be numeric.

Comment: The example has text for those values.

Comment: @Tomalak, that was after the OP updated the Q, and i added a comment for that case

Comment: @Neal: Ah, ok. Well, now we know!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't like the answers above using PHP to concatenate, you can use Javascript to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTotal(food, pizza, drink) {
   document.getElementById("total").value = food + drink + pizza;
}
</script>

<form method="get" name="fname" action="" onSubmit="addTotal(document.fname[0].value,document.fname[1].value,document.fname[2].value)" >
Food <input name="food" type="text"  size="1" />
Pizza <input name="pizza" type="text"  size="2" />
Drink <input name="drink" type="text" size="2"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="" />
</form>
```

And in your PHP file, you now should get

```
$_GET['food'];
$_GET['pizza'];
$_GET['drink'];
$_GET['total'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$sep = ""; //if you want a space in between each just change this to a space.
$concat = implode($sep, array($_GET['food'], $_GET['pizza'], $_GET['drink']));
```