# How to pass variable to PHP picture

Tags: php

Motivated by this post
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form I want to display my images by

```
<?php $pathToPicture = "server/www/images/imagexyz1823014719102714123.png"; ?>

<img src="/resources/php/showImage.php"  >
```

where showImage.php is simply given by

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($pathToPicture);
?>
```

But how can I pass the variable *$pathToPicture* to *showImage.php*? I do not want to hard-code *$pathToPictue* into *showImage.php*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables in php using GET without type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074699/how-to-pass-variables-in-php-using-get-without-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the path of image as get parameter to showImage.php script like.

```
<?php $pathToPicture = "server/www/images/imagexyz1823014719102714123.png"; ?>

<img src="/resources/php/showImage.php?pathToPicture=<?php echo $pathToPicture;?>"  >
```

Here you can get passed variable from `$_GET` array:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($_GET['pathToPicture']);
?>
```

I preferably suggest use of base64_encode and base64_decode for `pathToPicture` for this purpose. Also not expose the whole path of your images location openly like this. Have a look at below improved code

```
<?php $pathToPicture = "imagexyz1823014719102714123.png"; ?>

<img src="/resources/php/showImage.php?pathToPicture=<?php echo base64_encode($pathToPicture);?>"  >

<?php
    $location = "server/www/images/";
    $image = !empty($_GET['pathToPicture']) ? base64_decode($_GET['pathToPicture']) : 'default.jpg';

    // In case the image requested doesn't exist.
    if (!file_exists($location.$image)) {
        $image = 'default.jpg';
    }

    header('Content-Type: '.exif_imagetype($location.$image));
    readfile($location.$image);
?>
```

Comment: Remember to sanitize the input, otherwise you're asking for a lot of trouble

Comment: @TheCodingMonk is it enough to call htmlspecialchars or what would you recommend to sanitize?

Comment: Check that the passed path is effectively pointing to the image folder, otherwise somebody could read arbitrary files on the server